# (Debian 9, Stretch) Update Nvidia Cuda Compilation Tools from Version 8 to the newest version?

Tags: debian, nvidia

Nvidia does not provide the Cuda Compilation Toolkit for Debian hence using the Ubuntu version [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) but

```
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Sep__4_22:14:01_CDT_2016
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.44
```

which is the same as [here](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/nvidia-cuda-toolkit), i.e. 8.0.44 version; only experemental package available [here](https://packages.debian.org/source/experimental/nvidia-cuda-toolkit) about the newest version 10 and

```
$ nvidia-smi
Mon Jul  1 10:26:48 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.116                Driver Version: 390.116                   |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro P5000        Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   50C    P8     9W /  N/A |    951MiB / 16275MiB |      1%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

where I cannot see any version number.

I am all the time getting the old version installed even though downloading the newest version 10.

**How to updgrade the Cuda Compilation Tools to the newest version?**

Answer (score 0):

I installed it using the unstable dependency because of outdated stable dependencies such that

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian experimental main
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ unstable main contrib non-free
```

where you notice the `experimental`, `unstable` and then run

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt fullupgrade
```

**Cuda**

```
$ sudo apt -t experimental install nvidia-cuda-toolkit nvidia-detect cuda
```

**Setup**

```
$ nvidia-smi 
Tue Jul  2 11:42:44 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.74       Driver Version: 418.74       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro P5000        Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   47C    P8     4W /  N/A |    540MiB / 16275MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2018 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Jun_12_23:07:04_CDT_2018
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.2, V9.2.148
$ nvidia-detect 
Detected NVIDIA GPUs:
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP104GLM [Quadro P5000 Mobile] [10de:1bb6] (rev a1)

Checking card:  NVIDIA Corporation GP104GLM [Quadro P5000 Mobile] (rev a1)
Your card is supported by the default drivers and legacy driver series 390.
It is recommended to install the
    nvidia-driver
package.
```